# Given $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ differentiable, $f(x + y) = f(x)f(y)$ and $f(0) = 1$, prove $f(x) = e^{cx}$, $c$ constant.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

Given $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ differentiable, $f(x + y) = f(x)f(y)$ and $f(0) = 1$, prove $f(x) = e^{cx}$, $c$ constant.

**Attempt:**

Differentiate $f(x + y) = f(x)f(y)$ with respect to $y$ using the chain rule:
$f'(x + y) = f(x)f'(y)$.

Let $y = 0$ to get $f'(x) = f(x)f'(0)$.

Rearrange to get $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = f'(0)$.

Integrate both sides with respect to $x$ to get $\ln f(x) = f'(0)x + c$ where $c$ is the constant of integration.

Take exponentials of both sides to get $f(x) = e^{f'(0)x + c} = e^{f'(0)x}e^{c}$.

Since $f(0) = 1$, we get $f(0) = e^{f'(0) \times 0}e^{c} = e^0e^c = e^c = 1$.

Plugging this back in we get $f(x) = e^{f'(0)x}$ and setting $f'(0) = c$ we get $f(x) = e^{cx}$.

**Question**

Is this correct? One concern I have is at the integration step where the logarithm of $f(x)$ is taken. Is that legal given that we do not know whether $f(x)$ is strictly positive?

Comment: @plop $f(0) = 1$

Comment: Differentiating wrt $x$ does not give $f'(x + y) = f(x)f'(y)$

Comment: Sorry, I meant $y$. I'll edit.

Comment: The solution seems fine to me.

Comment: Depending on your definition, you could just stop at $f'(x) = f'(0)f(x)$. Many people take $\exp$ to be defined as the differentiable function $f$ satisfying $f'(x) = f(x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, we can easily show $f(x) > 0$ for all $x$.

$f(x) = f(x/2)^2 \ge 0$

$f(x)f(-x) = f(0) \ne 0$

So $\ln f(x)$ is perfectly well-defined. Everything else looks fine.

(For an extra challenge, show that this is also true if we only assume $f$ is continuous. For a real extra challenge, show that it's not true in general.)

Comment: IIRC you can even weaken beyond continuity to measurability, but I think to proceed that way, you need to recast this as an integral equation. It's a good bit messier. I recall doing this in my master's but that was X years ago now and details are fuzzy.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Yeah, nonlinear additive functions have really nasty properties. Not only are they nonmeasurable, they're also unbounded on every interval.

Comment: It is already true under very mild conditions, e.g., when there exists a interval where $f$ is bounded

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen TIL, that's pretty cool.